# Restrict my Android application to allow it to make request only to a certain domain?

Tags: android, security

I want to demonstrate to the users that my application is safe because it only makes request to a certain domain, and its subdomains, and no where else. Therefore, any potensially sensitive data won't get leaked.

- Is there a way for me to restrict it in such a way? That is, I want to restrict my future application in this way. If it's via manifest.xml, how precisely?
- Is there a way to also prove that to my future users?
- Will making it open source be the only way? Or are the standard security settings, in the UI, that would allow that? Such as a checkbox "Restrict this app to make requests ONLY to domain123.xyz"

And some users, of course, may not be technically savy. Therefore, simply making it open source may not necessarily convence those users.

The version of Android - one the latest ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way for me to restrict it in such a way?

No, sorry.

Comment: sorry for what? You are the one who's removed that ability?

Comment: are you aware of the alternative ways to archive that? They may not be perfect.

Comment: @Kum: "sorry for what?" -- I am sorry that this feature does not exist for you. "are you aware of the alternative ways" -- there are none, as far as I know.